# Understanding PHP If and else syntax in HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to understand how to use if and else statement in php together with HTML div tags. I've seen http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp but it looks different from the working example below. Why do some php if and else statement have so many opening `<?php` and closing `?>`

Working example

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
<?php 
$headerImg = get_header_image();
if( !empty( $headerImg ) ) { ?>
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="" />
<?php } 
else {
echo get_bloginfo( 'name' );
} ?>
</a>
```

My Attempt to include html div

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
<?php 
$headerImg = get_header_image();
if( !empty( $headerImg ) ) { ?>
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="" />
<?php } else {
echo "<h2 class='site-description'>"<?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>"</h2>";
} ?>
</a>
```

**Error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'**

Comment: Maybe you want to use `heredoc` for something like this?

Comment: @Class Why? Those are one-liners between conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain the previous style, do something like this:

```
<?php } else { ?>
<h2 class='site-description'><?php echo bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem was you already had an open PHP tag and you were trying to open another one. To do it that way, do this:

```
<?php } else {
    echo '<h2 class="site-description">', bloginfo( 'description' ), '</h2>';
} ?>
```

Note that I've updated the quotes and used commas to give you maximum performance.

---

To answer your question about too many PHP tags:

- in the first example, PHP is used only for conditions - to call one snippet of HTML if a condition is true, and the other if it is false. Also, when you want to inject a PHP output (from a variable, a function, etc), you need the PHP tags again (though there's a safe short code for that: `<?= $var ?>` is the same as `<?php echo $var; ?>`. This is why you open and close the PHP tags so often.
- in the second example, PHP is used to generate the HTML output (the echo function), and this is why we remain in a single PHP tag and handle it all from there

Neither of them is good nor bad. It depends on what you need. Ideally, you'd want to avoid writing the spaghetti code (mixing languages) completely, by having all the PHP variables in one place, and the presentation HTML in other (and using `<?= $var ?>` to insert PHP variables in a template-engine fashion).

Comment: You're welcome! Also, to explain why I said max performance: single-quotes in PHP are faster than double-quotes (talking about milliseconds here) because no parsing takes place... comma method for echoing is faster than the dot method since no concatetion takes place (combining all string into one and then printing it, as opposed to printing them one by one, as they come).

Comment: @BabyAzerty, yes, I just explained in the previous comment, not only that it works, but will give you a better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```
echo "<h2 class='site-description'>"<?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>"</h2>";
```

by

```
echo "<h2 class='site-description'>" . bloginfo( 'description' ) . "</h2>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php } else {
echo "<h2 class='site-description'>"<?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>"</h2>";
} ?>
```

should be

```
<?php } else {
echo "<h2 class='site-description'>".bloginfo( 'description' )."</h2>";
} ?>
```

Everything inside the  tags gets interpreted as PHP, everything else is just send straight to the browser.
You are trying to open a PHP tag although you're already in PHP, this leads to the error.

A good text editor with syntax highlighting would help you spot those errors and better understand the concept. Check out [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for an open source alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot put a php tag inside of php tag.

you should make sure that whenever you open a php tag, you need to close it before opening another.
I suggest you to use an editor that shows you colours and errors while you write your code.

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
<?php 
$headerImg = get_header_image();
if( !empty( $headerImg ) ) { ?>
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="" />
<?php } else {
    $desc = bloginfo( 'description' );
    ?>
    <h2 class='site-description'><?php echo $desc; ?></h2>;
    <?php } ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?=esc_url(home_url('/'));?>" title="<?=esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name'));?>" rel="home">
<? if(!empty(get_header_image())):?>
<img src="<?=header_image(); ?>" height="<?=get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?= get_custom_header()->width; ?>" />
<? else: ?>
<h2 class='site-description'>"<?=bloginfo('description'); ?></h2>
<? endif; ?>
</a>
```

Use short tags if you can and alternative if syntax to make your template more readable.